# Laravel. Изменить папку с "public" на "public_html"?

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация, hosting

Кто подскажет, мжно ли каким-то образом заменить папку расположения сайта в проекте на Laravel с "public" на "public_html" ?

Comment: то есть вы хотите отдавать статические файлы с другой папки? Не совсем понятно что Вы имеете ввиду под "заменить папку расположения сайта"

Comment: на хостинге вместо папки "public" используется папка "public_html". перенаправление через .htaccess не работает(

Comment: Самое простое - сделать символическиую ссылку с `public` -> `public_html`

Comment: Загляните в файлы `server.php` и `config/filesystems.php`.

Comment: если у вас на сервере public_html корень сайта, то в эту папку и кидайте все приложение, папка public внутри приложения служит для внутренней маршрутизации, вам нет необходимости это менять

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаешь laravel в папку с public_html (не в саму папку). Далее удаляешь папку public_html. Далее делаешь символическую ссылку `ln -s public public_html`

Comment: у вас явная опечатка в названиях каталогов (в каком именно месте ­— вам виднее). исправьте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit].